# time out error while connecting url

Tags: android

i am new to android. in this application i created a login page where user can only login if that username and password matches with username and password in the url but in response it show empty string and it catches exception of time out error. here is the code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button button;
        String connectionString, params;
        PackageManager  pm;
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        DatabaseHelper mydb;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                        String userNameString = username.getText().toString();
                        String passwordString = password.getText().toString();
                        String url = "http://122.160.78.189:85/mobile/loginUser?";
                            String params = null;
                        try {
                            params = "userName=" + URLEncoder.encode(userNameString, "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passwordString, "UTF-8") + "&appVersion= 1.22";
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        new Mytask().execute(url, params);

                    }
                   }


            }));

        }


        class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            // Runs in UI before background thread is called
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                setProgressBarVisibility(true);
                // Do something like display a progress bar
            }
            // This is run in a background thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                return getFromServer(params[0], params[1]);
            }
            // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                try {
                    checkLogin(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public String getFromServer(String connectionString, String params) {
                String response = "";
                try {
                    // android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                    URL url = new URL(connectionString);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    //con.setConnectTimeout(100 * 1000); //10 Seconds
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                    con.setUseCaches(false);
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(params);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                    response = read(is);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    return response;
                }
            }
            private String read(InputStream in) {
                BufferedReader reader;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    return response.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use volley for network data transmission. It is easy to implement and give you retry settings

Comment: `where user can only login if that username and password matches with username and password in the url` ??????????????

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
     HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
     HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new  

     URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");


   con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds

   return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);

  } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
  return false;
 } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
  return false;
```

}

Comment: try to use volley library

Answer (score 0):

You can increase connection and read timeout time.

```
con.setConnectTimeout(connectiontimeout);
con.setReadTimeout(readtimeout);
```

You can use [retrofit] http://square.github.io/retrofit/

For your current code, this server response is, 
{"userId":0,"userName":null,"name":null,"password":null,"role":0,"email":null,"mobile":null,"department":null,"selectedState":null,"selectedmainGroup":null}